# Wpf-how can I use a converter in order to display elements from a listbox while I am scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have a big lists of objects which are binded to a ListBox. In that list box i am displaying the name of a file and a byte array of an image which is coming form WCF. I would display the files in the listbox depending on the scroll postion, so the file which are not visible from that scroll position to be set as Hidden.
I found on the internet a way which might help me but i cannot see a way that this will work.
I found convertors which should help me, and set up that class as a window resource. When I am opening the app all the items are converted to be visible.
This is the class:

```
class NullVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null ? Visibility.Hidden : Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value == null ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Hidden;
    }
}
```

In Xaml i setup this class as a window Resource and i binded the functionality to the image and name in the Listbox items

```
        <Window.Resources>
            <view:NullVisibilityConverter x:Key="NullToVis"/>
        </Window.Resources>
    <Image  Source="{Binding Path=Image}" Visibility="{Binding Path=Image, Converter={StaticResource NullToVis}}" Height="80" Width="80" Grid.Column="0"/>
   <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding Path=Image, Converter={StaticResource NullToVis}}" Orientation="Vertical" Width="80" Height="30">
   <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Margin="5,1,0,1"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Does anyone have any idea how this might work?

Comment: All this should work out of the box by [virtualization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879(v=vs.100).aspx), which is done by default in a ListBox or ListView.

Comment: Thank you @Clemens this is what i was reading now. It might be helpful

Comment: With a lot of struggle I got no results. I don't know what i am doing wrong, but I am looking again after the Convertor.

Comment: @AlexandruFlorin-Ciprian why do you need the files which are not visible to be hidden, can you provide a screenshot of what you are experiencing to clarify? As Clemens says, this behaviour is the default, so I'm a little confused about exactly what you are experiencing...